# How to use BatchAsync to get pictures id of all albums on facebook with C#

Tags: c#, facebook

I can get pictures id of whole albums on facebook.. But it takes long time.. Maybe I can use BatchAsync to get ids. You know that firstly we need albums id after access to picture id.. so I use two GET functions for result.. I think I can use BatchAsync for it.. But I dont know how can I use it (with query or get method..)

here is my code.. maybe somone needs it

```
        string pics="";

        var albums = (JsonObject)client.Get("/me/albums"); 

        foreach (var album in (JsonArray)albums["data"])
        {
            var albumsPhotos = (JsonObject)client.Get((string)(((JsonObject)album)["id"]) + "/photos");

            foreach (var aalbum in (JsonArray)albumsPhotos["data"])
            {
                var photoID = (string) (((JsonObject) aalbum)["id"]);
                pics += "ID: " + photoID.ToString() + "\n";

            }
        }

        MessageBox.Show(pics);
```

as you see, there are two foreach loops and its not good.. :) I also used getasync.. but its slower than get function..